# What happens if using latest Firebase on devices with old Google Play services?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

As I see on release notes, usually it says:

> Firebase Android SDK v.x is part of the Google Play Services v.x
>   release.

So let's say I use Firebase SDK 9.8.0 in my project for ads and push notifications. What happens on a device that does not have the latest Google Play Services updated?

Comment: in my experience, my app showing prompt dialog to download latest google play services.

Comment: and the ads/push notifications etc. do not work until the user updates? So for instance it could use the app without seeing ads?

Comment: i don't know about ads & push notification, but in my case i'm just using firebaseauth. if user didn't update play services to latest version then firebaseauth won't work. i think you should try it with emulator using non-google api images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is using an older version of the Google Play Services, the user will get a dialog prompting to update it to the latest version. Some services like the Firebase Authentication might not work if the user doesn't update.